# Windows returning output to input audio

Tags: audio, microphone, phone

My Windows is returning output audios to input. It allow, for instance, if I'm in a Skype conference, my friend can listen to what I'm listening (music, video, generic sounds like a click, etc.).

What configuration do I need to make it work correctly?

I'm running Windows 7 64bit (updated) and I use a headphone - can it be a problem (if it is broken)?

In sound manager, if I click in Window Volume bar (to make the "blin blin blin" sound) it returns to input (microphone) too!

Comment: Do you have " stereo mix " selected in the audio properties.

Comment: How I can know about that? I don't found nothing about "Stereo Mix". Thx

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `sndvol32` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Go to Options, then Properites
- In the "Mixer Device" drop down box, choose your *input* service e.g. "Realteck HD Audio Input"
- In the "Show the following volume controls" check the "Stereo Mix" and click **OK**
- In the new window uncheck "Stereo Mix" and close

Skype usually does this automatically but give it a try.

Comment: If you mean "Win+R" doesn't exists "sndvol32", only "sndvol", it open the volume mixer dialog. But in this dialog doesn't exists "options", "properties" or "mixer device" dropbox. :(